# python 3: How to rearrange dictionaries in list by new variable without adding new key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rearrange dictionaries with new variable which is newly defined with existing variables. 
For example,

```
security_info = [{'date': '19.04.15', 'price': 785000, 'trade': 79620},
                 {'date': '19.04.16', 'price': 785000, 'trade': 68203},
                 {'date': '19.04.17', 'price': 754000, 'trade': 165929},
                 {'date': '19.04.18', 'price': 779000, 'trade': 94462},
                 {'date': '19.04.19', 'price': 770000, 'trade': 76814},
                 {'date': '19.04.22', 'price': 774000, 'trade': 58079},
                 {'date': '19.04.23', 'price': 775000, 'trade': 79128},
                 {'date': '19.04.24', 'price': 771000, 'trade': 61650},
                 {'date': '19.04.25', 'price': 757000, 'trade': 111805},
                 {'date': '19.04.26', 'price': 764000, 'trade': 68237}]
```

I want rearrange this list by 'net return', which is defined by 'price today/price yesterday *100' (of course 'net return' of first date does not exist). 
But I don't want to solve this by adding new key and value.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what the output should look like?  Not sure what you mean by "rearrange this list by 'net return'" but not by "adding new key and value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should preface this by making a few comments:

1. This is not a great structure for these data. I would recommend looking into [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which can handle dates and would work well in this situation.
2. Making a new value for the net return would probably be a good idea, since this is what you are using to sort the values by.

Nevertheless, if you want to sort the values based on the net return, **and the list is currently sorted by date** (as in your example), then something like this could work:

```
def net_return(entry): 
     i = security_info.index(entry) 
     if i>0: 
         return security_info[i]['price']/security_info[i-1]['price'] 
     else: 
         return -1 

sorted(security_info, key=net_return)
```

This returns the following list:

```
[{'date': '19.04.15', 'price': 785000, 'trade': 79620},
 {'date': '19.04.17', 'price': 754000, 'trade': 165929},
 {'date': '19.04.25', 'price': 757000, 'trade': 111805},
 {'date': '19.04.19', 'price': 770000, 'trade': 76814},
 {'date': '19.04.24', 'price': 771000, 'trade': 61650},
 {'date': '19.04.16', 'price': 785000, 'trade': 68203},
 {'date': '19.04.23', 'price': 775000, 'trade': 79128},
 {'date': '19.04.22', 'price': 774000, 'trade': 58079},
 {'date': '19.04.26', 'price': 764000, 'trade': 68237},
 {'date': '19.04.18', 'price': 779000, 'trade': 94462}]
```

Hope this helps.